# Passing FBSDK login manager result between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I can't transfer the login manager result between view controllers,
The segue is associated to the button and its identifier is s1.
My setup is correct.The program is crashing with green breakpoints.
here is my code:
for the first  VC:

```
import FBSDKLoginKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var user_name: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
                print("Failed to get access token")
                return
            }

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)


            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, id, locale"])
                .start(completionHandler:  { (connection, result, error) in
                    guard let result = result as? NSDictionary,
                        let user_name = result["user_name"] as? String,

                        else {

                            return
                    }

                    if(segue.identifier == "s1"){
                        if let v = segue.destination as? Re {


                            v.uname=user_name ?? ""



                            //v.uname = usr.text ?? ""
                        }
                    }              


                })


            // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    return
                }



            })

    }


    }


}
```

And for Re,the next VC:

```
class Re: UIViewController {
    var uname: String?    
    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!
    var userfb: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
l1.text=uname
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instance variable which you have declared at top as below.
Now you have create new `user_name` and use another `user_name`

```
guard let result = result as? NSDictionary,
                        user_name = result["user_name"] as? String,// make change here

                        else {

                            return
                    }
```

Comment: value of type NSDictionary not unwrapped,did you mean to use ? or !

Comment: this is your code . i have just removed local variable and use your global variable . i

Comment: the program is still crashing.I. just want to pass Facebook login manager result between view controllers.i have read a lot of similar codes to do it